# Limit for a SQL Server query (to be used for pagination)

Tags: sql-server-2008, pagination, limit

I've got a large query that pulls back contacts based upon a search. Here's a simplified example of the query. (Table and field names have been changed to protect the innocent.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 DB1.FieldID, DB1.Field1, DB.Field2, DB.Field3,
DB2.Field88, DB3.Field77
FROM tblLamp DB1
LEFT JOIN tblSand DB2 ON DB2.FieldID = DB1.FieldID
LEFT JOIN tblLime DB3 ON DB3.FieldID = DB1.FieldID
WHERE (Field1 LIKE 'hotwet%' ESCAPE '!' OR Field2 LIKE 'maarten%' ESCAPE '!')
AND DB2.Field99 != '1111-2222-3333-4444'
AND (DB1.CreatorID IN (...) OR DB1.OwnerID IN (...) OR DB1.FieldID IN (...))
ORDER BY DB1.Field1 ASC, DB1.Field2 ASC
```

I've found a lot of examples on the web that use ROW_NUMBER() but I haven't been able to get it working with this query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this small example as a guide:

```
declare @test table(id int, name varchar(255));
insert into @test
  select 1, 'one' union
  select 2, 'two' union
  select 3, 'three' union
  select 4, 'four' union
  select 5, 'five' union
  select 6, 'six';

select
  *
from
(
  -- select the columns you need and include row number to enable limit 
  select
    name,
    row_number() over(order by id) as rownumber
  from
    @test
) v1
where
  rownumber between 2 and 4
```

Comment: I used something similar to this. Thanks for your help.